# DisplayMessageActivity cannot be resolved to a type-Building first android App

Tags: java, android

Hi I have just began working on the first android application on **developer.android.com**.

well to start with I got to learn many error origins and their solutions from S.O. , but i have been trying to figure out this statement 
*"DisplayMessageActivity cannot be resolved to a type"* while we have to set an Intent for button onclick function. It shows this error in the line where the code line is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

here is the java file:

**MainActivity.java**

```
}
/**called when the user clicks the send button*/
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity (intent);
}
}
```

I tried a lot find which class do I need to import now, and searched but no avail.
may be I am a beginner is what I miss here.

Comment: Do you have an Activity named `DisplayMessageActivity` ?

Comment: and where should it be in the code?

Comment: I saw that you have an Activity named 'MainActivity', but there should be another Activity(probably a new class extending `Activity`) 'DisplayMessageActivity' which you are calling from your Intent.

Comment: then I guess I dont have DisplayMessageActivity defined. how can I make it then separately?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent (this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);` actually calls a new Activity(DisplayMessageActivity). Create another class similar to your present `MainActivity`, name it as DisplayMessageActivity. Add its entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Run your program.

Comment: ok ok understood that, I have added new activity what possibly do I need to remove this error from there now. It still seems to be there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, I think it's too late to answer and probably you figured out already.
However, just in case I'd like to put some more explanation.

Probably their "Starting Another Activity" section of Buidling Your First App" was revised after you posted your question, but I found that the user-defined "DisplayMessageActivity" is defined several lines below where you were guided to write code to create Intent and thus refer to DisplayMessageActivity.
At "Create Second Activity" section, the DisplayMessageActivity is created.

Well, Google's pedagogy style is not good, and I found out that their framework design ( and thus naming ) is not good and doesn't reveal what they are.
But.. if you choose Android platform to develop for, what can you do other than endure that. Good luck with that.

Comment: yeah I pretty much got it by now!

Comment: Even now, their Getting Started guide has this problem, so this answer helped me out.

Comment: There is a note now. And I understand their approach - they want to make it understandable and interesting for beginners.

Comment: And by the way - you learn the most when things are not working as expected :) If everything is working you learn very little (just my opinion).

Comment: @damian1baran Absolutely correct! BTW I have come a long way now, and am a Professional Android developer. ;) learned a lot via this Community!

Answer (score 5):

In that tutorial of developing first app, they create DisplayMessageActivity.java later part of tutorial. Please read the complete tutorial. The documentation have been corrected to indicate the same when using IDEs. You can visit here :

> ```
> Note: The reference to DisplayMessageActivity will raise an error if you’re using an IDE such as Eclipse because the class doesn’t exist yet. Ignore the error for now; you’ll create the class soon.
> ```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

Answer (score 0):

DisplayMessageActivity is not a class predifined by android packages, so you should create it as ordinary java class and call from yours, here, MainActivity. Sure it doesn't require to be named as in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can create the display message activity class yourself by adding this code anywhere
public class DisplayMessageActivity {
     }