# Android Studio cannot find class DisplayMessageActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm learning android development on https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent

I try to start an activity and write `Intent intent=new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);`

but the IDE tells that **cannot resolve symbol `DisplayMessageActivity`**

So I compare my packages with the example code on the link above, and in the example code it has a package `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, while I only have `android.suport.v4.balabala`

What can I do?

Comment: complete reading the guide (https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#CreateActivity), you will get the answer

Comment: I'm sloppy on my Chinese, but the trainings seems to declare `DisplayMessageActivity` in code and in the Manifest.  Have you already done that?

Comment: Check Android Udacity course. That is very helpful to learn basics of Android. Happy coding.

Comment: well...my fault. i didn't completely read the doc

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [DisplayMessageActivity cannot be resolved to a type-Building first android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190256/displaymessageactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-building-first-android-app)

The thing is you have to create the activity before starting it, it is not default. The way to create it is some lines below. Check it here: https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#CreateActivity

Comment: I tripped over the same issue: the name "DisplayMessageActivity" looks like it was some class from a standard application, not one in the sample project. Q&A saved me a lot of time and frustration